# How to use password characters (like *) in MATLAB GUI

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface, passwords, matlab-guide

I want the user to see password characters (* or other) when inserting string in a text box. I know in the file-exchange we have some codes like this : [Password dialog](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8499-login) but I want create this structure in GUIDE manually because my window has more elements in it besides password text box. I think we can use some java codes to have this structure in our GUI.

How can I do this? How we can have other characters like circle in text box? (like windows text boxes for password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file exchange entry you reference has the building blocks you need, but you'll need to do some work to restructure them into your own GUI. Basically, that UI registers a KeyPressFcn to overwrite the contents of the text entry field with asterisks (after remembering the contents).